# Remove any space beyond the square with data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the general `mtcars` data as an example.

I create a quick `geom_point()` with two variables:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23)
```

[image]

What I want is to remove everything beyond the "gray-matrix" square.

For instance, I removed the axis, titles and ticks:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

However, in this figure there is still a white area between the gray area and the external limit of the image.

This can be visualized in RStudio. In the next image I show the "white" margin that still persists in the plot:

[image]

My question, therefore, is how can I remove that white area beyond the gray square, so that the square takes full space?

Comment: Try:  `+ theme_void()`

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/e9p5z7/removing_white_borders_in_ggplot/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *theme_void*

> "A completely empty theme."

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 0:4, y = 0:4), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 23) +
  # "A completely empty theme."
  theme_void() +
  # set expansion to 0 to remove more white space
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  # check
  theme(panel.background = element_rect("yellow"))
```

[image]